# How to remove Emgu CV UI ImageBox the scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

How to remove the scroll bar

`WPF` + `C#` + `Emgu CV` UI  There's a scroll bar, I set it up

```
capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight, 1024);
```

Because video frame height and width is higher than UI height and width

```
private void OpenCv(ref  VideoCapture capture, int index = 0)
    {
        if (capture == null)
        {
            capture = new VideoCapture(index);
            if (capture.IsOpened)
            {
                capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Autofocus,0);
                capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight, 1024);//设置捕捉到帧的高度为320  Width="246"  Height="210"
                capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth, 1024);//设置捕捉到帧的宽度为240
                capture.FlipHorizontal = false;//捕捉到帧数据进行水平翻转
                capture.ImageGrabbed += eventHandler;
                capture.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                capture = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Xaml

```
<wfi:WindowsFormsHost ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"    >
    <emui:ImageBox   Enabled="False" 
                     AllowDrop="False"
                     AutoSize="True"

                     AutoScrollOffset="0,0"
                     x:Name="capturedImageBox" 
                     Paint="CapturedImageBoxPaint" />
</wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your WindowsFormsHost inside a ScrollViewer if you did not do it already and set its properties inside its tag.

I mean;

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ...>
 <wfi:WindowsFormsHost ...>
 //...
 </wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
</ScrollViewer>
```